# In Solidity, Is it possible to pass a struct as a parameter between contracts?

Tags: solidity, struct

I have a struct in contract A, and want to pass it to contract C via contract B.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, using `experimental ABIEncoderV2`.

```
contract first{

    struct dataStruct {
        uint value;
        address addr;
    }

    dataStruct public data1;
    dataStruct public data2;

    constructor() public {
        data1.addr = msg.sender;
        data1.value = 7;
    }

    function passdata(address ic) public {
        first r = first(ic);
        r.recdata(data1);
    }


    function recdata(dataStruct data) public returns (uint, address) {
        data2.addr = data.addr;
        data2.value = data.value;
    }

}
```

The example above can be deployed twice (same code deployed twice, 2 different addresses) and you can set the data2 structure of the first deployed contract to the value of the structure `data1` of the secondly deployed contract.

The constructor is setting the values of the structure, change these on each deployment.

Hope this helps

Comment: This passes a struct that is stored in the storage but not in memory.